# How to fetch twitter account information from iPhone's addressbook

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook

I can see post , which fetch information from addressbook but i cant get any reference that how to get the twitter account details  for a given phone no from iPhone's address book

Please let me know, how to get that information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible.
Try using one of the constants below in

> **The predefined constants are used to identify social networking services. You may use these constants or any other string.**
>   
>   const CFStringRef kABPersonSocialProfileServiceTwitter;
>   const CFStringRef kABPersonSocialProfileServiceGameCenter;
>   const CFStringRef kABPersonSocialProfileServiceFacebook;
>   const CFStringRef kABPersonSocialProfileServiceMyspace;
>   const CFStringRef kABPersonSocialProfileServiceLinkedIn;
>   const CFStringRef kABPersonSocialProfileServiceFlickr;
>
> *Available in iOS 5.0 and later.*

With something like this:

```
ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonSocialProfileServiceTwitter);
```

Comment: basvk : thanks for the reply, can i able to send tweet to that partcular tweet account? is that possible ? please help me out

Comment: if you want to "send" a tweet to that tweet account, you have mention him (@person) in the message body. If you want to send a DM (direct message) you have to follow eachother. Sending tweets and stuff can be done, just google for it.